# How do I get the results of a multiple choice field from Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I set up a model multiple choice field, where a user can select multiple choices. I want to be able to get the choices that a user selected when filling out the form. What can I call to get the results that the user picked? Also, how would I iterate over those results (what does it return)?

Here's the field:

```
CHOICES = MyMultipleModelChoiceField(queryset=MODEL.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Too little information

Answer (score 0):

Your post is incomplete there is too little informations you can to the following.

Use CreateView to create a new instance and then grab your data from your db, it will look like :

```
class CategoryCreate(generic.CreateView):
form_class = your_form_class
model = your_model

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('your_view')
```

And in your next view you will be able to grab the data from your model.